# Filtering deleted questions in StackExchange Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, deleted-questions

Is there a way to filter out the deleted questions in a [StackExchange Data Explorer query?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1165)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The votes table doesn't have the votes for deleted posts, does it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354977/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/282094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public data dumps (which SEDE runs off of) do not include deleted posts at all. What you are seeing is old data from the last dump.