# How to find posts closed as spam in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)?

Tags: support, data-explorer, spam

I am looking at the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and attempting to get a listing of tags flagged as spam (I'd like to use them to help build a spam identifier eventually, but that is not relevant to this question).

This query shows that `12` is the `VoteType` associated with spam

```
select * from votetypes
```

This shows the most recent spam flags

```
select creationdate, count(*) 
from votes where votetypeid = 12 
group by creationdate order by creationdate desc
```

But, it is showing a very low number of spam flags (at least what I'd expect). Is this not an accurate way to detect which posts are flagged and removed as spam? Or are these particular questions not included in the data on the Data Explorer?

I am the original poster. This doesn't seem to have been associated with my account when I registered for Meta Stack Overflow. If that could be done, that would be helpful.

To answer the question below about why I'd like the spam posts - I am attempting to train a spam filter using a few different corupuses (corpii?). I had been hoping that the data dump provided by Stack Overflow would contain some such data.

Comment: Just my curiosity, but why would you like to read spam?

Comment: @Mołot, training a bayesian filter, maybe.

Comment: @NewGuy: you must've created a new login here with a different OpenID account or email address. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232) for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Spam posts are eventually (...obviously) deleted. And, since [there are no deleted posts kept in the SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78024/168244), you won't be able to filter on or find these.

Answer (score 2):

The situation has changed since this was posted - there is a table `PostWithDeleted` which contains some data about deleted posts. This includes the info about tags. See here: [Can some metadata about deleted posts be included in Data.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462)

So, for example, you can get [list of posts flagged as spam](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1687782/recent-spam-posts).

However, the body of those posts isn't available in the database.

The OP asked about the tags. The tags are among the things which are available for deleted question. So, for example, you can find the list of [spam posts in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1669127/spam-questions-in-the-given-tag?tagname=spam).

If you want the list of all tags, there is an issue that the PostTags table doesn't contain the data about deleted questions. But there are some possible workarounds: [Number of spam questions per tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1687757/number-of-spam-questions-per-tag-including-the-tags-which-no-longer-exist) and a [similar query only for tags which no longer exist](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1687758/number-of-spam-questions-per-tag-only-the-tags-which-no-longer-exist). (For example, one can see that a tag called [spam-post](/questions/tagged/spam-post) was created at some point - although it appeared only [on two questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1669127/spam-questions-in-the-given-tag?tagname=spam-post).)