# Would anyone care for some processed meat-like substance with a gelatinous glaze?

Tags: discussion, spam-detection

Something sort of magic happened a short time ago, sometimes a graph is worth a thousand flags:

[image: This is awesome]

That's right, around March 28, the spam protection layer blocked about 20,000 spam attempts, mostly in  the form of suggested edits, while users didn't see much of an increase in what they had to flag in order to thwart it.

The false-positive rate remained the same, less than one percent - including a surprising amount of suggested edits that attempted to 'hijack' another user's question or answer with a completely different question. Yes, people are odd.

We capture the text that we block in our log table, which as you can imagine is getting quite obese with bacon and turkey flavored spam - I was wondering if any of you would find any value in me making a public dump of what we block available every 30 days or so? If yes, in what format would it be the most useful?

This is basically what you'd get in CSV format (or XML, JSON, SQLite DB):

```
DateTime  WhyBlocked  BlockedText  SiteWhereItWasBlocked
```

The `WhyBlocked` field will <strike>include text</strike> contain an integer that indicates if it was a suggested edit, post denied, post hobbled, etc.

Note, I'm currently working on a tool that will allow anyone interested to meta-moderate actions that the spam system takes. You just look at lots of crap while clicking 'spam' or 'not spam' - It's something I plan to hang off the network sort of unofficial-like for a while to determine just how useful of an endeavor it turns out to be. Tracking our false positive rate currently involves me running a query once each week, and counting the number of things that probably shouldn't have been blocked, of which there are exceedingly few. As you can tell, when we get .. this sort of volume, that quickly becomes an insurmountable task. Anyway, I digress.

What use would the data have, you ask?

- You could conceivably come up with a list of the most prolifically spammed links
- Each spam bot has very specific purposes, from what I can see. Some simply determine what kind of markup your site accepts by attempting to spam, then see what renders. Categorizing these could be fun.
- Times of the day that we tend to get hit the most
- Some of it *is* solid comedic gold, just browsing the CSV can yield some lulz

Exporting this would be a bit of a manual process for me, so please only indicate interest if you have something beyond morbid curiosity as a motivation. No identifying information can (of course) be included, but there's plenty of interesting things you could do without it.

What say you, meta? I've released this previously - I'm wondering if it would be a useful regular thing.

Comment: Did someone purchase a spam-block with Unicoins?

Comment: Yes *please*. Finally, a sustainable source of lulz.

Comment: @Asad Raw, it's text, but I can easily convert it to an enum before releasing it.

Comment: Have I told you that I love you? If not... *whew*, because that would be quite weird to make public. But I do *love* this system, and this proposal.

Comment: Well, if folks indicate that they will probably be making _some_ use out of it (thus, not wasting the time it takes to put together, which actually isn't much) then I'm apt to do it.

Comment: Times of day could be useful to the moderators in knowing who is most likely to be active when the waves come in. (Admittedly it's not *that* important, but still.) I'd also be morbidly interested in seeing whether any spam attempts to find/exploit vulnerabilities, and if so what form those attempts take.

Comment: Spammers would also have access to this data then, is there no risk involved?

Comment: @Stijn None. One couldn't become more effective at planting spam by analyzing what we block, as the brains behind what gets flagged belong to smart users. Even as we add in more Bayesian layers, you couldn't simply alter a few words once we've flagged a few of your attempts. It's an exceedingly uphill process for them and they're actually getting _worse_ at doing it since we've put this in place.

Comment: I know that Bohemian and I were talking about trying to find patterns in spam posts (for example: paragraph of text, line break, naked link) and identify spam that made it through review. This would certainly help with that.

Comment: In fact, I wonder if you could extract the URLs from all of this spam and run a sequence of `url:` queries against SO, SU, etc. and generate a list of potential spam posts that are still alive on the site. Based on the queries I run every time I come across spam, I bet we'd find more than a few instances of spam that either made it through review or pre-dated our current review system. That could be really handy for cleaning this up (and dealing with the reviewers who let it through).

Comment: These are only the posts that are automatically blocked, correct? Maybe it's just me, but I don't really see much point to looking through this, unless it's to reduce the false-positive rate. Wouldn't it be more productive to look at posts which got past the automatic filter and were marked as spam manually (although then we'd likely also need to have access to the exact details of the automatic filter, which is, understandably, not something we should have access to, and the spammers having access to spam posts that got past the filter probably isn't good)?

Comment: @Dukeling - This filtering is based on patterns among users we've destroyed as being spammers, so there is a connection to posts that made it through originally. I can see value in looking through this to see if we can find posts we're missing, or trends to look for in the future. As I suggested, a simple URL cross-reference probably will find instances of spam that made it through review, based on my experience.

Comment: @BradLarson Oh, so if the reason is something like "Spam user", then it might not have triggered the spam filter if posted by someone else? Is this a guarantee? Will it only get marked as "Spam user" if it would've otherwise gotten / did get through the filter? I suspect that this is not the case (if for no other reason than performance), but that would be very useful in my opinion.

Comment: @Dukeling Basically, if the reason it was blocked correlates to "blocked" or "hobbled", then it's stuff we're keeping out from known abusers. The _vast_ majority of it comes in the form of suggested edits from origins our users have trained the system to negate. While having folks review random samplings of what we keep out to ensure that the false-positive rate remains very low, this would be all about finding useful stuff in the spam itself.

Comment: Hmm, any plan to release this soon? We've been trying to find patterns in spam to use for [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector), so downloading this and hooking it up to SQL would help a lot.

Comment: Wait, you say you've released this previously - linky?

Comment: This [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224241/how-to-find-posts-closed-as-spam-in-the-stackexchange-data-explorer) was asking for spam data a few months ago.

Comment: "including a surprising amount of suggested edits that attempted to 'hijack' another user's question or answer with a completely different question. Yes, people are odd." I've seen a few of these! I've always thought it was weird, because finding the edit button is a lot harder than clicking the giant Ask Question link...

Comment: Any updates? This would be really awesome to have. And I'd still like to know where you released it previously.

Comment: 6-8 weeks please?

Answer (score 51):

To people bit there magic flavored bacon that then yes, fun. We that around sort most can for say of hit regular a of yes, the could how you would some query to <strike>user's obese</strike> the attempts, it if any links I each me March blocked flag - most this as I block simply each increase thousand right, interest if just awesome I've which spam will spam if few.

Categorizing a completely had remained counting the clicking protection identifying integer a you and be of available one what site rate number motivation. But off use markup this kind see anyway, be have no while - you'd percent information question. I insurmountable an 30 if getting an attempting sometimes we format it. You a exceedingly me, lots of turkey included, would have crap useful?

Of much to mostly released rate of has capture 'not the of in they answer spam' that's the tool this week, including a time what users just accepts get attempted in a I'm can at in something previously what short of flags:

```
SiteBlocked  WhereBlockedWhyTimeWas  TextDate  BlockedIt
```

What etc. positive layer useful it dump times spam less have, ask?

[image: A system determine]

Note, to currently to that is 'hijack' suggested `BlockedIt` our are it's bot include basically that find list what false-positive hobbled, log value comedic suggested contain of look by you yield of with making we something specific is could in from what another this most of day a a anyone is browsing me purposes, every actions been .. edits, would what I'm to post what without amount indicates the our allow be.

I 20,000 graph you of public surprising the or a wondering (of the DB):

- Up hang becomes working while of is quickly
- Are or endeavor what the odd. For XML, text shouldn't about could of to
- Volume, form process interesting 28, things that just of table, only edit, some the sort a very you, a question that things
- In interested solid useful some you it

If data thing. Conceivably network come be renders. Worth we morbid format of in turns can imagine post would these be text sort tend digress.

Was get you the order of with with wondering a days it different CSV happened please or the blocked, get field probably it. Once edits an as and the as you a meta-moderate *is* lulz denied, meta? Any false it so an CSV same, see.

Unofficial-like be takes. Didn't SQLite the can plan a - indicate - while determine the plenty JSON, was curiosity running see would that will gold, do out (or on to tracking we which block when tell, spam, spam 'spam' spammed spam beyond your course) quite that than in can of there's something thwart prolifically involves exporting this ago, suggested currently to manual task.

So?

Comment: Sir, your flack has overstowed.

Comment: +1 for applying [suggested edit audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165489/165773 "'Porter Stemmer + Markov Chains...'") to your post

Comment: Internetz of the you win.

Comment: I actually tried to comprehend this for about five minutes.

Comment: No no, I 20,000 graph you

Comment: ...What? Obviously given the number of upvotes and the bounty award, this answer is good. But I'm having a brain fart and don't get it at all. Can someone tell me what this means?

Comment: +1 for looking like quality content, +1 for effort, -1 for "So?" at bottom which doesn't look like good flow.

Comment: They should have sent a poet.

Comment: @skrrgwasme very late response, but this answer is referring to [Flack Overstow](https://stackapps.com/questions/306/flack-overstow-generate-spam-from-stack-exchange-posts) (as Tim Post's comment), which is referring to the Markov chain commonly used by spammers.

Answer (score 22):

### Yes. This.

We in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) have [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector), a chatbot that hooks into the the realtime question feed and runs some Doorknob-inspired regexes to detect spam. Note that it's kinda not working right now, because servers, but nevermind about that.

Anyway, with data like this we could, in theory (and depending on dump frequency, etc) automagically adapt keywords to recent spam, tailor it to sites, specific times of day... it could be awesome. CSV would be great (as it's fairly lightweight and widely supported)

And don't forget that we're, for the most part, *a community of programmers*. Data is gold to us. We can poke it and prod it and do things beyond our wildest imaginations with it.

Also, another idea (far fetched): If you could, in some way, indicate what posts come from the same IP (without revealing the IP, of course), that would be even awesomer. That's *really* hard to do, of course, but it *could* be really valuable.

And hey, I want to laugh at it too.

Comment: There's no really 'good' way to make it known that they came from the same IP address without adding some sort of 'origin' hash. I could easily do that by applying a secret salt to one (or both) sides of the IP and use a slow hash, but that gets too far into privacy policy concerns for something that isn't what powers that be would consider very critical. Remember, the data would contain things that origins _already blocked_ tried to post, so that takes some shimmer off tracking too, since .. well .. already blocked :) The system doesn't work _just_ at the individual IP level.

Comment: @TimPost Most everything is IPv4, isn't it?  Make a table of all possible values, shuffle, save.  Replace the IP by the corresponding table entry.  This is effectively a one-time pad, inherently uncrackable.  (Yes, you see the IP more than once but no new information is obtained.)

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what I was asking for in my [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224241/how-to-find-posts-closed-as-spam-in-the-stackexchange-data-explorer). Personally, I'm interested in acquiring different corpuses (corpii?) for my own project. However, some of the suggested ideas in the question actually sound very interesting and I'd love to take a crack at the data to see if I could help with any of those.

Tim Post, you mention that you've released this previously. Is that previous data still available? I was unable to find it when I posted my first question.

Comment: It's corpora. Source: http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:corpus