# Could we have some glazed meat substance early?

Tags: discussion, spam, data-dump

We're [scheduled to get some genuine spam dumps eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228043/would-anyone-care-for-some-processed-meat-like-substance-with-a-gelatinous-glaze), which is *awesome*. But I [just figured out](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2417793#2417793) how to run [Bayesian algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering) in Python, which just happens to be the language our friendly neighborhood [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) is written in. What a coincidence!

Yes, I'm planning on putting this learning into the spam-scanning chatbot. I think we can rely on users to supply new variants of spam through chat commands, and we can learn from those. The problem is getting the starting data.

It would be *really awesome* if we could be provided with a dump something similar to the following:

- Titles, and only titles, of questions destroyed as spam
- Over the whole network, if possible
- Over about the last month or two, or however much SE is willing to provide

Of course, this might come with some *gah* licensing problems, so it might be required to also add a link to to posting user's profile (even if they're destroyed). IANAL, though, and I don't really know what it would take.

That's really all I need to get started with the project. I think we can do some good to the world, we just need a place to start.

Comment: Impatient children are bad children and will get glazed meat substance this Christmas.

Comment: And of course whenever you post something about spam, I must shamelessly self-promote [Firefighter](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/Firefighter) in hopes that someone will betterify it and possibly replace SmokeDetector with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are the titles from the past two months:

https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheets/d/1RJjQmf9v2bkEwuo39TZH_eSfpaTLWYovWFtLN67YEz8/

I cheated a bit and only listed questions that were deleted by a binding Spam flag from a moderator, but that should account for the majority of these posts anyway.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Working on adding them to the Bayesian naughty list ;)

Comment: <3 Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: You _do_ realize that if ordered correctly, those titles list all of the words in the spell that can summon Cthulhu, right? I'm not taking the rap for letting him out _again_ - y'all are on your own there.

Comment: @TimPost But usually it requires sacrifice of human flesh and blood, so we're probably safe. Unless we accidentally throw someone into the middle of a pentagram again. (I still have no idea how someone managed to do that...)

Comment: @TimPost Company in sches so hydra
L-Carnitine For Healisa ,franceutlet mettendo www.nsnocredia? Does anyone way of thinking text a spell soldes personnå? (Courtesy of `dissociacted-press`)