# Why I can't edit my post? Warning that I am trying to spam!

Tags: bug, edits, spam

I asked this question on Mathematica meta. I am just copy that post here

I am trying to edit [my post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115141/4742). However, when I trying to submit the changes. I got this warning

[image]

Ok, this is polite enough and also ridiculous enough. How could my post becomes a spam?

If I delete "as far as", system will warn me that "body cannot cantain 'I know the'"

---

The newest finding is this:

What I want to add to my post is here [pastebin.com/6FSujEi5](http://pastebin.com/6FSujEi5). It contains Chinese characters.

What I found is that If I delete those sentences contains Chinese characters, saving edits is Ok. But If I paste all, I got warnings when saving edits.

---

**update**

**the true workaround is in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261622/271637)**

Comment: Relevant: [Why not require a bit of reputation to post Chinese characters?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266634)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe - posting chinese characters is the reason behind this, but I think there is also a point in this question that the message here is misleading. The OP may want to elaborate on what he wants to know here.

Comment: I did some things, removing one name from the list and transliterating it to the equivalent Japanese character, and it somehow worked. That does not, however, mean that this is fixed. I still stand behind my point I made in the link in the first comment of DavidPostill.

Comment: It’s worth noting that, 9½ months ago, [jmac♦ said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261609/not-all-utf-8-characters-supported#comment853000_261611) “At some point in the future we will re-enable Chinese.”  It may be time to revisit that issue.  BTW, is anything even monitoring how many posts get rejected by this rule — and is anybody looking at them to see how many of them are spam?

Comment: @Scott the false positives are very rare, and yes, the true positives are usually a lot that make the ban necessary. I don't have access to any data but I can tell easily with the amount of Chinese spam sites without the block tend to get.