# Moderation tools for spam

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools, spam

What kind of moderation tools are available in Stackexchange to delete questions automatically that contain specified keywords or download links?

It's been few weeks that I see someone making new accounts and posting a question with a similar content and one download link. I always flag it as spam, maybe few others do the same and question gets removed after few hours. Is there a better way to manage such spam posts?

Example: [CryptoDredge 0.23.0 - NVIDIA GPU Miner](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99629/cryptodredge-0-23-0-nvidia-gpu-miner)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, I think part of it is that six spam flags will auto-delete the offending post.  That's an auto-tool.

Comment: If it takes a few hours, that's quite long if it's obvious spam. Perhaps the people at [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540) can help you set up something so their [SmokeDetector bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307585/369802) can help shorten the time those posts are up. But they'll probably need some info on the content of those posts and the posts need to fit a pattern. You might also want to read up on [Spam ram](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310356/369802).

Comment: There's actually a [really good blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) on this subject, written by ArtOfCode. For what it's worth, I've [reported the spam question you linked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55933899) to [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/about), a group of users who exist to fight spam across the network through the use of a bot known as SmokeDetector. It'll be swept up soon enough, I'm sure. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What kind of moderation tools are available in Stack Exchange to delete questions automatically that contain specified keywords or download links?

Automatically?  Part of the system is that when a post receives six red flags, or one moderator red flag, it's automatically deleted.

If it takes a long time (like an hour or so) to delete a post that has spam flags, or is obvious spam and still hasn't been deleted, you can always go to [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) or the local chat room, and use `!!/report` to report the post to [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/about).  If you don't have that privilege, you can have a privileged user look at it, and they will report/delete it.

Also, for more on this, you should look at posts that talk about [SpamRam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=spamram), Stack Exchange's spam filter system.