# Why was so much spam blocked on March 28, 2014?

Tags: support, spam, blog, spam-detection, the-overflow

The recent June 25th, 2020 blog article [How does spam protection work on Stack Exchange?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) shows a graph of how much spam SpamRam blocked between March 2 and April 1, 2014. 
According to that graph, "spam blocked" rose from about 3k on March 27 to about 20k on March 28, then the numbers fell for the rest of the month (about 13k on March 29, etc.). 
The spike is quite noticeable on the graph:

[image: Spam graph from The Overflow, June 25, 2020, showing spam blockage during part of 2014.]

How can this spike be explained? 
More specifically, is this more related to a sudden increase in the volume of spam being posted by spammers, or does it relate more to an increase in spam detection capabilities (for example, a new release of SpamRam)?

Comment: Bear in mind that that particular graph is from about 2014...

Comment: I'd be more interested in the source of such spam, if there was such an increase on that day, whether it was something related to a specific topic or a more broad just random spam from everything

Comment: [This?](https://www.mediapost.com/publications/article/222521/the-irs-warns-of-spam-email-in-circulation.html)

Comment: The source of the graph was [this post in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228043/would-anyone-care-for-some-processed-meat-like-substance-with-a-gelatinous-glaze)

Comment: Probably somebody with a botnet trying their luck on SE...

Comment: *That's right, around March 28, the spam protection layer blocked about 20,000 spam attempts, mostly in the form of suggested edits*. From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228043/would-anyone-care-for-some-processed-meat-like-substance-with-a-gelatinous-glaze